# How would I test this equation for symmetry?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^{ 2 }y^{ 2 }+xy=1$$

I know the procedures to test for symmetry with respect to the x axis, y axis, and origin... but I think that I wouldn't be able to do that here without first manipulating the equation. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Let $A:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\colon x^2y^2+xy=1\}$. For symmetry with respect to the $x$-axis you want to check if, given $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$, the statement $(x,y)\in A\implies (x,-y)\in A$ is true. For symmetry with respect to the origin you want to see if $(x,y)\in A\implies (-x,-y)\in A$ holds.

Comment: What are the procedures you know? Why don't they apply here?

Comment: We have symmetry about $y=x$ only I think. Do you know how to check that?

Comment: Well if I was to check for the symmetry with respect to the x-axis I would replace y with -y. My question is how would I go about setting up this equation so that it would be in the format $$y=...$$ Is that even a necessary step for this problem?

Comment: No, it's not necessary to do that.

Comment: In fact, you could quite easily sketch the graph by solving the equation to get $xy=\cdots\,$.  Then you could just look at the graph to identify symmetries and you would not need any algebraic tests.

Comment: I am attempting to do this algebraically.

Comment: I substituted values for x and y. Got rid of the 1.

$$(2)^{ 2 }(3)^{ 2 }+(2)(3)=19$$
$$(-2)^{ 2 }(-3)^{ 2 }+(-2)(-3)=19$$

So there is symmetry with respect to the origin? Or am I going about this the wrong way...

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a pair of hyperbolic functions, symmetric about $y=x$ and $y=-x$.

The easiest thing to do to see this is to just solve for $y$ to discover the 2 equations.

Suppose $t=xy$, then $x^2y^2+xy=1$ becomes
$$t^2+t=1$$
By the quadratic formula
$$t=\frac{1}{2}(1\pm\sqrt{5})$$
which means that
$$xy = \frac{1}{2}(1\pm\sqrt{5})$$
thus
$$y = \frac{1}{2}(1\pm\sqrt{5})\cdot\frac{1}{x}$$
which is a pair of hyperbolic equations (because of the $\pm$) of the form $\displaystyle y=\frac{c}{x}$